# Python Flask Flash Not Displaying At All

Tags: python, flask, flash-message

I am working on a project at work for taking in large excel files and spitting them out in PDF form.

My code is at https://github.com/haincha/Project

It has the template file and all.

For some reason I just can't find good documentation or I am terrible at life.

**Figured it out**

Code was working, was missing:

```
app.secret_key = 'some_secret'
```

Everything else was good.

```
flash(Markup(str(count) + " file(s) have been converted into PDF."))
return render_template("upload.html")
```

This is what happens when I am reading documentation after a long day.

Comment: You need to include specifics of what you have tried.

Comment: This is a completely valid question. Why would somebody write methods using flash into Flask 0.12.4 when it doesn't work. There is obviously an import statement missing from the code on: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: It's corrected in version 1.0 which is (now) the latest stable version

Answer (score 5):

You're not actually calling the `flash` function anywhere.

Following the example in the [official documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/flashing/):

In your view function you need to call `flash`

```
flash('You were successfully logged in')
```

Only then will the call to `get_flashed_messages` in the Jinja template return any data.

Comment: Using flash in my flask 0.12.4 container I get the errors: builtins.NameError
NameError: name 'flash' is not defined

Comment: @EamonnKenny `from flask import flash`